# How to proof "If $0 < x < 1$, then $x^2 < x$"

Tags: real-analysis

> Justify by using the properties of ordering:
> If $0 < x < 1$ , then $x^2 < x.$

How to proof the claim above? I am allowed to use the following facts:

- For all $x,y\in\mathbf{R}$, $$x<y\Leftrightarrow y-x>0$$
- The set of real numbers equals the following [disjoint union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint_union):$$\mathbf{R}=\mathbf{R}_{<0}\sqcup\{0\}\sqcup\mathbf{R}_{>0}$$
- $x+y\in\mathbf{R}_{>0}$ and $x\cdot y\in\mathbf{R}_{>0}$ for all $x,y\in\mathbf{R}_{>0}$

Comment: "How to prove it" depends completely on what axioms and methods of proof you are allowed to use. Could you please provide us with that information? Otherwise, there is no way for others to tell what sort of proof would be allowed in your class.

Comment: I think the best approach would be to show that, whenever $x \in [0,1)$ and $y$ is strictly positive, we have $xy < y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $0 < x < 1$,
$$x^2 = x\cdot x < x \cdot 1 = x$$

Answer (score 1):

$$x^2<x\iff x^2-x=x(x-1)<0$$

...and then you can produce an algebraic proof (cases) or a simple geometric proof by using that $\,x(x-1)\;$ is an upwards parabola vanishing at $\,x=0\;,\;x=1\;$ ...

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious proof is:

[image]

whose solution is (algebrically):

[image]

Or, geometrically,

[image]

Anyway, as Carl Mummert said, "how to prove it" depends on the axioms and methods of proof you are allowed (or supposed) to use. So feel free to ask if you need something different.